# Android: How to draw route directions google maps API V2 from current location to destination

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

How to draw route direction from current location to destination which (latitude and longitude), i have code as below:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class DetailMapActivity extends SherlockActivity {
    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_detail_map);

        LatLng TO_DESTINATION = new LatLng(-6.33438, 106.74316);

        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(TO_DESTINATION).title("Destination Title")
                .snippet("Destination Description"));

        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(TO_LOCATION, 40));

        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
    }
}
```

I want to draw from current location by provider network or gps, and then draw the route by driving to destination.

I'm using android google apis V2.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

This works great for me:
**It's not my code**, I took it from a great answer at stackoverflow but I can't find this answer now, so here is the code:

Add this class to your project:

```
package ...;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

public class GMapV2Direction {
    public final static String MODE_DRIVING = "driving";
    public final static String MODE_WALKING = "walking";

    public GMapV2Direction() {
    }

    public Document getDocument(LatLng start, LatLng end, String mode) {
        String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?"
                + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude
                + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude
                + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving";
        Log.d("url", url);
        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                    .newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(in);
            return doc;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getDurationText(Document doc) {
        try {

            NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
            Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
            NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
            Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
            Log.i("DurationText", node2.getTextContent());
            return node2.getTextContent();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "0";
        }
    }

    public int getDurationValue(Document doc) {
        try {
            NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
            Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
            NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
            Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
            Log.i("DurationValue", node2.getTextContent());
            return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public String getDistanceText(Document doc) {
        /*
         * while (en.hasMoreElements()) { type type = (type) en.nextElement();
         * 
         * }
         */

        try {
            NodeList nl1;
            nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");

            Node node1 = nl1.item(nl1.getLength() - 1);
            NodeList nl2 = null;
            nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
            Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
            Log.d("DistanceText", node2.getTextContent());
            return node2.getTextContent();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "-1";
        }

        /*
         * NodeList nl1; if(doc.getElementsByTagName("distance")!=null){ nl1=
         * doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
         * 
         * Node node1 = nl1.item(nl1.getLength() - 1); NodeList nl2 = null; if
         * (node1.getChildNodes() != null) { nl2 = node1.getChildNodes(); Node
         * node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value")); Log.d("DistanceText",
         * node2.getTextContent()); return node2.getTextContent(); } else return
         * "-1";} else return "-1";
         */
    }

    public int getDistanceValue(Document doc) {
        try {
            NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
            Node node1 = null;
            node1 = nl1.item(nl1.getLength() - 1);
            NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
            Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
            Log.i("DistanceValue", node2.getTextContent());
            return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return -1;
        }
        /*
         * NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance"); Node node1 =
         * null; if (nl1.getLength() > 0) node1 = nl1.item(nl1.getLength() - 1);
         * if (node1 != null) { NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes(); Node node2
         * = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value")); Log.i("DistanceValue",
         * node2.getTextContent()); return
         * Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent()); } else return 0;
         */
    }

    public String getStartAddress(Document doc) {
        try {
            NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("start_address");
            Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
            Log.i("StartAddress", node1.getTextContent());
            return node1.getTextContent();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "-1";
        }

    }

    public String getEndAddress(Document doc) {
        try {
            NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("end_address");
            Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
            Log.i("StartAddress", node1.getTextContent());
            return node1.getTextContent();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "-1";        
    }
    }
    public String getCopyRights(Document doc) {
        try {
            NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("copyrights");
            Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
            Log.i("CopyRights", node1.getTextContent());
            return node1.getTextContent();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        return "-1";
        }

    }

    public ArrayList<LatLng> getDirection(Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1, nl2, nl3;
        ArrayList<LatLng> listGeopoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("step");
        if (nl1.getLength() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < nl1.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
                nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();

                Node locationNode = nl2
                        .item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "start_location"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                Node latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
                Node lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));

                locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "polyline"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "points"));
                ArrayList<LatLng> arr = decodePoly(latNode.getTextContent());
                for (int j = 0; j < arr.size(); j++) {
                    listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(arr.get(j).latitude, arr
                            .get(j).longitude));
                }

                locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "end_location"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
                lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
                lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
                lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
            }
        }

        return listGeopoints;
    }

    private int getNodeIndex(NodeList nl, String nodename) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            if (nl.item(i).getNodeName().equals(nodename))
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private ArrayList<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;
        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;
            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng position = new LatLng((double) lat / 1E5, (double) lng / 1E5);
            poly.add(position);
        }
        return poly;
    }
}
```

Then use this class for your needs.
For example to draw directions:

```
GMapV2Direction md = new GMapV2Direction();
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
Document doc = md.getDocument(sourcePosition, destPosition,
                    GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING);

ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint = md.getDirection(doc);
            PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(3).color(
                    Color.RED);

            for (int i = 0; i < directionPoint.size(); i++) {
                rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));
            }
            Polyline polylin = mMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
```

The `sourcePosition, destPosition` are from the LatLng type, and you give them the wanted points.

I wrote here parts from my code that I think could help, Any question is welcome.

Comment: For those who are looking for original post, please check out this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15053901/1468354

Comment: This is old, but this code runs the network on the main thread. Just to alert people. +1 for providing the source as well. Awesome piece of code.

Comment: Are there any restrictions from google? for example amount of requests?

Comment: Any limits or restriction using this api?

Comment: @dvrm You are actually using XML parsing for this solution?  Isn't there a RESTful service for this.

Comment: getDurationValue or Text give me wrong duration value (58 min always). Solution is easy, go to the last node, change this Node node1 = nl1.item(0); line for this Node node1 = nl1.item(nl1.getLength() - 1);

Comment: @dvrm Hi, is it possible to add multiple direction with this??

Comment: can we make polyline with arrow indication

Comment: keyless API already deprecated, you need an API Key which requires billing now.

Comment: I have two location, start and end. And how can i use this code to draw direction on button click.

Answer (score 10):

Using the dvrm solution **GMapV2Direction class**, it's a good solution and it's still working, but now you need to implement the getDocument method in a new thread to allow network connections. This is an example for an AsyncTask for this method, the rest of the class is the same. You can handle it with a Handle or implement your own interface callback to get the Docmuent xml response.

```
public class GMapV2DirectionAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Document> {

private final static String TAG = GMapV2DirectionAsyncTask.class.getSimpleName();
private Handler handler;
private LatLng  start, end;
private String mode;

public GMapV2DirectionAsyncTask(Handler handler, LatLng start, LatLng end, String mode) {
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
    this.mode = mode;
    this.handler = handler;
}

@Override
protected Document doInBackground(String... params) {

    String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?"
            + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude
            + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude
            + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=" + mode;
    Log.d("url", url);
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                .newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(in);
        return doc;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Document result) {
    if (result != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "---- GMapV2DirectionAsyncTask OK ----");
        Message message = new Message();
        message.obj = result;
        handler.dispatchMessage(message);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "---- GMapV2DirectionAsyncTask ERROR ----");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
}
```

}

This is the async handler method for the activity:

```
    protected void route(LatLng sourcePosition, LatLng destPosition, String mode) {
    final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            try {
                Document doc = (Document) msg.obj;
                GMapV2Direction md = new GMapV2Direction();
                ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint = md.getDirection(doc);
                PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(15).color(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.magoo_user_base_color));

                for (int i = 0; i < directionPoint.size(); i++) {
                    rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));
                }
                Polyline polylin = googleMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
                md.getDurationText(doc);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    };

    new GMapV2DirectionAsyncTask(handler, sourcePosition, destPosition, GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING).execute();
}
```

One more thing, if the duration value is wrong, solution for it is to change one line of the code of GMapV2Direction class:

```
Node node1 = nl1.item(nl1.getLength() - 1);
```

instead:

```
Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's too late but worth. I have searched and tried a lot of example but didn't get desired result so I found this amazing library which give you the desired result. You have to write bunch of line.

> Link: https://github.com/jd-alexander/Google-Directions-Android

**Import library:**

> implementation 'com.github.jd-alexander:library:1.1.0'

I am implementing the code inside onMarkerClick so If a user click on marker then it will route from his current location to marker location but you can change this as per your requirement.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        Routing routing = new Routing.Builder()
                .travelMode(AbstractRouting.TravelMode.DRIVING)
                .withListener(MapsActivity.this)
                .waypoints(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), marker.getPosition())
                .key("AIzaSyDGvkmJ6osdJz7v8OSg7U")
                .build();
        routing.execute();
        return false;
    }
```

**Implement RoutingListener**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, RoutingListener
```

**Override Methods**

```
   @Override
    public void onRoutingFailure(RouteException e) {
        Log.e("check", e.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onRoutingStart() {
        Log.e("check", "onRoutingStart");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRoutingSuccess(ArrayList<Route> route, int shortestRouteIndex) {

        Log.e("check", "onRoutingSuccess");
        CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(latitude,longitude));
        CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16);
        List<Polyline> polylines = new ArrayList<>();

        mMap.moveCamera(center);


        if (polylines.size() > 0) {
            for (Polyline poly : polylines) {
                poly.remove();
            }
        }

        polylines = new ArrayList<>();
        //add route(s) to the map.
        for (int i = 0; i < route.size(); i++) {

            //In case of more than 5 alternative routes

            PolylineOptions polyOptions = new PolylineOptions();
            polyOptions.color(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRouteLine));
            polyOptions.width(10 + i * 3);
            polyOptions.addAll(route.get(i).getPoints());
            Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(polyOptions);
            polylines.add(polyline);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRoutingCancelled() {
        Log.e("check", "onRoutingCancelled");
    }
```

*Here* is the example project you can check this code as well.

> https://github.com/jd-alexander/Google-Directions-Android/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/directions/sample/MainActivity.java

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here i am posting complete code for drawing route between current location and another place on google map.

For more details : [Visit draw route on google map with current locatio](https://demonuts.com/android-google-map-draw-path-between-current-location-and-destination/)n

PointParser class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class PointsParser extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

    TaskLoadedCallback taskCallback;
    String directionMode = "driving";

    public PointsParser(Context mContext, String directionMode) {
        this.taskCallback = (TaskLoadedCallback) mContext;
        this.directionMode = directionMode;
    }

    // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            Log.d("mylog", jsonData[0].toString());
            DataParser parser = new DataParser();
            Log.d("mylog", parser.toString());

            // Starts parsing data
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);
            Log.d("mylog", "Executing routes");
            Log.d("mylog", routes.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("mylog", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
        // Traversing through all the routes
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            points = new ArrayList<>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);
            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                points.add(position);
            }
            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            if (directionMode.equalsIgnoreCase("walking")) {
                lineOptions.width(10);
                lineOptions.color(Color.MAGENTA);
            } else {
                lineOptions.width(20);
                lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
            }
            Log.d("mylog", "onPostExecute lineoptions decoded");
        }

        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        if (lineOptions != null) {
            //mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
            taskCallback.onTaskDone(lineOptions);

        } else {
            Log.d("mylog", "without Polylines drawn");
        }
    }
}
```

FetchURL class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;


public class FetchURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    Context mContext;
    String directionMode = "driving";

    public FetchURL(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        // For storing data from web service
        String data = "";
        directionMode = strings[1];
        try {
            // Fetching the data from web service
            data = downloadUrl(strings[0]);
            Log.d("mylog", "Background task data " + data.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        PointsParser parserTask = new PointsParser(mContext, directionMode);
        // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
        parserTask.execute(s);
    }

    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);
            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();
            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            data = sb.toString();
            Log.d("mylog", "Downloaded URL: " + data.toString());
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("mylog", "Exception downloading URL: " + e.toString());
        } finally {
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener , OnMapReadyCallback, TaskLoadedCallback{

   //variables for map and route

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private MarkerOptions place1, place2;
    Button getDirection;
    private Polyline currentPolyline;
    private MapFragment mapFragment;
    private boolean isFirstTime = true;

//variables for current location
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private TextView tvLocation;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mLocation;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener listener;
    private long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 2 * 1000;  /* 10 secs */
    private long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 2000; /* 2 sec */

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //code for getting current location
        requestMultiplePermissions();

        tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.tv));

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();


    }

    //code for drawing route

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.clear();
        Log.d("mylog", "Added Markers");
        mMap.addMarker(place1);
        mMap.addMarker(place2);

        CameraPosition googlePlex = CameraPosition.builder()
                .target(new LatLng(22.7739,71.6673))
                .zoom(7)
                .bearing(0)
                .tilt(45)
                .build();

        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(googlePlex), 5000, null);
    }

    private String getUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest, String directionMode) {
        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;
        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;
        // Mode
        String mode = "mode=" + directionMode;
        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + mode;
        // Output format
        String output = "json";
        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters + "&key=" + getString(R.string.google_maps_key);
        return url;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskDone(Object... values) {
        if (currentPolyline != null)
            currentPolyline.remove();
        currentPolyline = mMap.addPolyline((PolylineOptions) values[0]);
    }

    //runtime permission method

    private void  requestMultiplePermissions(){
        Dexter.withActivity(this)
                .withPermissions(
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION )
                .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
                        // check if all permissions are granted
                        if (report.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All permissions are granted by user!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        // check for permanent denial of any permission
                        if (report.isAnyPermissionPermanentlyDenied()) {
                            // show alert dialog navigating to Settings
                            openSettingsDialog();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {
                        token.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                }).
                withErrorListener(new PermissionRequestErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onError(DexterError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some Error! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .onSameThread()
                .check();
    }

    private void openSettingsDialog() {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Required Permissions");
        builder.setMessage("This app require permission to use awesome feature. Grant them in app settings.");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Take Me To SETTINGS", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                intent.setData(uri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 101);
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        builder.show();

    }


   //methods for getting current location

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }

        startLocationUpdates();

        mLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if(mLocation == null){
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
        if (mLocation != null) {

            // mLatitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mLocation.getLatitude()));
            //mLongitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mLocation.getLongitude()));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Location not Detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection Suspended");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed. Error: " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        // Create the location request
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
                .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        // Request location updates
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                mLocationRequest, this);
        Log.d("reque", "--->>>>");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        String msg = "Updated Location: " +
                Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," +
                Double.toString(location.getLongitude());

        tvLocation.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude() +"    "+String.valueOf(location.getLongitude())));
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if(isFirstTime){
            //code to draw path on map

            getDirection = findViewById(R.id.btnGetDirection);
            getDirection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    new FetchURL(MainActivity.this).execute(getUrl(place1.getPosition(), place2.getPosition(), "driving"), "driving");
                }
            });

            place1 = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())).title("Location 1");
            place2 = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(20.8880, 70.4012)).title("Location 2");
            mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapNearBy);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
            isFirstTime = false;
        }

     }

}
```

If you have any error then check out original tutorial given at the starting of this answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_detail_map);
    .....
    .....

  /* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */
  LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

  LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
  mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
}

/* Class My Location Listener */
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{

  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
  {
   CURRENT_LAT = loc.getLatitude();
   CURRENT_LNG = loc.getLongitude();
  }

  @Override
  public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
  {
    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
  }

  @Override
  public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
  {
    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  @Override
  public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
  {

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Gaurav, i have solved get current position just add this line map.setMyLocationEnabled(true); now how to draw direction by driving from current location to location destination. Thanks.