# How to navigate a car parked at some place

Tags: android, navigation

I was having a problem i parked my car in a crowded area. I  was not able to find it in rush.
 `Is there a way i navigate my car by using google maps or gps .` 
Please guide me how to start with it . What i thought is where my car parked i will pin the lat long of that area but how to proceed further. Since it is requirement of many customers i guess to find car in a crowded bunch of cars

Comment: well there is no way to actually use a GPS in your car without a phone in it or any android software.

Comment: I think you should start by buying a good introductory book on Android development it is there you will learn about the *OnMapClickListener* and *OnMapLongClickListener* interface and how you can use the LocationManager or MyLocation events to listen for GPS coordinate changes. These are all needed to solve your problem as is getting Google Maps API V2 to display which requires you to get an API key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well GPS is not that accurate to pin point the location of your car, GPS in commercial phones has an accuracy of about 30m at best checkout the article [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/answers/accurate-can-gps-mobile-phone/).

But still you can try as it may be better then we expect in some areas.
You should follow these steps:

- Get GPS Coordinates when you park the car (user clicks a button when
  he/she gets out of car) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1513569/3828908) is how to do that.
- When user is stuck in a crowded place, user should open the app and click find my car button.
- Clicking **find my car** should load google maps, show marker at the location you parked the car. [click this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html) [and this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker) for guidance.
- Get your location as in first point and [get directions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17007360/3828908) from your location to the cars location.

Abracadabra!
You are done :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Google Maps. 
   open google maps app on your phone.
   click on target like icon to get your location.
   mark the location.
   when you want to find your car... just click on the marked location and press get directions.
2. use a tracking device. cheap ones are also availableavailable
   Note- this is not the appropriate place to ask this question.A bit of googling would have helped.