# How to draw driving route from current location to destination by google map api lastest version (google play service 8.3)

Tags: android, google-maps

previously  I use  GmapV2 from [Android: How to draw route directions google maps API V2 from current location to destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444228/android-how-to-draw-route-directions-google-maps-api-v2-from-current-location-t). But now it's not work  I got error  about that class. How to fix that class?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add any code you have done so far.

Comment: Android GMaps service is working as expected. Please paste some code and also the stack trace of the error you are getting.

Comment: I'm sorry i can't answer  earlier. Here  code of class  GmapV2

Comment: Where? Still don't see it, lol.

Answer (score 0):

This code will draw the line from origin to destination.

```
@Override
public void onDirectionSuccess(Direction direction, String rawBody) {
    Log.d("Status", "Success");
    Log.d("Direction", "" + direction);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(origin));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(destination));
    if (waypoints != null){
        for (int i = 0; i < waypoints.size(); i++){
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(waypoints.get(i)));
        }
    }

    ArrayList<LatLng> directionPositionList = direction.getRouteList().get(0).getLegList().get(0).getDirectionPoint();
    mMap.addPolyline(DirectionConverter.createPolyline(this, directionPositionList, 5, Color.BLUE));

    Log.d("Status", "Success 2");
    showRoute.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```