# how to draw paths on actual roads between two location android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to draw a path between two locations using on android google map.I have tired this code

```
PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                // latitude and longitude
                double latitude = 0.00;
                double longitude = 0.00;


                Log.i("lat", cursor.getString(10));
                Log.i("lat", cursor.getString(11));


                try {
                    latitude = Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(10));
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

                try {
                    longitude = Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(11));
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
                if (latitude == 0.00 || longitude == 0.00) {

                } else {
                    i++;





                        LatLng point = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
                        options.add(point);



                    // create marker
                    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                            new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(cursor.getString(1));

                }

            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();


        googleMap.addPolyline(options);
```

but i got straight line.like this

[image: my map view]

I want to get paths on actual roads.

Thanks..!!

Comment: Please check this answer, let me know if this is what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17007360/2027644

Comment: gives me an error

Comment: Please elaborate the error

Comment: the error is google server not found   java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json

Comment: make sure you have google play services installed.

Comment: yes,and up to date

Comment: the error says "Missing the 'origin' parameter", so make sure u are supplying it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to draw a polyline between 2 points and following road, you can try with the library [Google-Directions-Android](https://github.com/jd-alexander/Google-Directions-Android)

You can add the library on gradle with `compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:library:1.0.7'`

You can use all your point (Latlng) and use them into the waypoint method.

```
Routing routing = new Routing.Builder()
                .travelMode(/* Travel Mode */)
                .withListener(/* Listener that delivers routing results.*/)
                .waypoints(/*waypoints*/)
                .build();
    routing.execute();
```

Comment: Yes. What you are doing is to get all your point (Latlng) and put them into the waypoint method.

Comment: What is the error ? You can't download the library from the compile command ?