# Android - User tracking google map?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2, android-maps-utils

I am using the `GPS` from android for tracker the user position by draw points in a map. The problem is the register of the points is inaccurate.

For example, when I see my points on the maps, it's look like this :

[image]

But I moved like below :

[image]

How can I position myself to accurately register my map?

Comment: which api you are using for getting current location?

Comment: Google map api v2 .I am creating an app for postman's.I need to records latitude and longitude them for show to managers.If you know a good library say me for use .Thanks a lot

Comment: Best library is Google Fused location provider, but i don't know if exist any provider with this precision, maybe you need somehow do an overlay in your map to only add the dots on streets, link to [FusedLocationProvider](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi)

Comment: I used from this but this is not exactly .

Comment: @JoJoRoid, Lucas Queiroz Ribeiro is right. you should use FusedLocationApi (i was talking about this :P). It will provide more accurate location coordinates and it is reliable to use.

Comment: You may want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37136981/draw-path-on-google-map-based-on-lat-lang/37682382

Comment: I used from FusedLocationApi  but get me point with 2 or 3 meter distance difference.