# Default Maps application vs In-app map in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

*Please don't mark this as duplicate or off-topic as any other answer on site don't cover my concern*.

I would like to use all features, accuracy, results provided by default **Maps** app in my Android in-app map.
I searched a lot over google for this however didn't get any luck over.
Even I couldn't get any blog or official doc which can direct me in a right direction or at-least can provide me the difference between features provided by both maps

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Which feature do you want to use specifically ?

Comment: @Debdeep I would like to use full feature rich map within Android app as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: You can still integrate most of the features in `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView`

Comment: @Debdeep I would like to get live traffic updates, live path(route) suggestion, accuracy etc like Maps app.

Comment: When you have your current location, you can simply enable traffic layer using `googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true)` and then  `googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true)` . Traffic data only loads after detecting the current location.

Comment: For routing, you may check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444228/android-how-to-draw-route-directions-google-maps-api-v2-from-current-location-t)

Comment: One thing though I got stuck with is changing language of places in the map. I restarted the fragment still nothing happens.